Pin swapping within same part in Altium?
Let's consider this level shifter. I can swap any pair Ax->Bx. In Altium if I add pin 10..13 in group 1 and pin 2..5 in group 2, I cannot ensure continuity between my nets. For instance if pin 10<->11 are swapped, this imply that 2<->3 must also be swapped.
Is this a way to configure this in Altium?


You could create a  multi-part component with a base part and each level shifter an additional individual part, but I'm not sure it's worth it.

I am not sure either :(
